# Upload xml file on ftp binary

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp, binary

i have code, where i send xml file to ftp server, but size of file on ftp server is smaller than original file. I'm trying to enable binary transmission, but result is still the same.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\data.xml");
            long original_vel = f.Length; 
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://***");
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*****");

            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\data.xml");
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            long ftp_vel = request.ContentLength;      
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (original_vel == ftp_vel)
            {
                response.Close();   
            }
            else
            {                
                Odesilani();
            }
```

The size of original file is 294 672, but the file on ftp have 294 670.
`The xml file on ftp is valid....But when i compare files in total comander, the original file have: FF FE 3C 00 3F 00.....and the file on ftp have 3C 00 3F 00...`But the content of file is ok...:/
Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the XML file at the server valid? From your code, You are reading the file using Unicode. Files that are encoded using unicode usually have a character that is placed at the beginning of the file called the [*Byte Order Mark*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) . That may be the reason you have a 2-Byte difference as it was lost during conversion.

**UPDATE** The Proper Byte Order Mark for any encoding is given by `Encoding.GetPreamble()`
The fix to the code above would be..

```
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\data.xml");

        //Get Preamble and File Contents
        byte[] bom = Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble();
        byte[] content = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());

        //Create Destination array
        byte[] fileContents = new Byte[bom.Length + content.Length];

        //Copy arrays into destination appending bom if available
        Array.Copy(bom, 0, fileContents, 0, bom.Length);
        Array.Copy(content, 0, fileContents, bom.Length, content.Length);


        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        long ftp_vel = request.ContentLength;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (original_vel == ftp_vel)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Odesilani();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the xml file is valid....But when i compare files in total comander, the origina lfile have: FF FE 3C 00 3F 00.....and the file on ftp have 3C 00 3F 00...But the content of file is ok...:/

Comment: If you still want it to be transferred with the rest of the content, you'll have to manually append it the beginning of the byte array.

`byte[] stuff = new byte[fileContents.Length+2];

`Array.Copy(fileContents, 0, stuff, 2, fileContents.length);

`stuff[0] = 0xff;

`stuff[1] = 0xfe;

fileContents = stuff;

Comment: There is no way to transfer the xml file in binary mode? Because when i try send *.exe file the result is horrible :/

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the System.Net.WebClient class. Its abstracts most of these issues.